# GPU Panic: Kernel panic when performing graphically intense tasks

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

I have been experiencing kernel panics roughly once per day since upgrading to Mavericks, but they overwhelmingly occur while I am doing something graphically intensive (eg: switching desktops, using Google Earth software). This one occurred out of the blue, during no irregular demands on my GPU.

In an effort to isolate the problem, I have uninstalled all third party kernel extensions.

I have a 2010 Macbook Pro and fear that it may be a logic card issue.

If so, can anybody explain what exactly this hardware issue is, and why the new OS is manifesting it?

```
Anonymous UUID:       5D28806A-97C9-B8D8-0E3E-6917ED04A07F

Sat Feb 22 23:21:36 2014 panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f97a11fac): "GPU
Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error
0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000
0xffffff80b6db5000 0x0a5480a2, D0,
P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.12/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff808d19b140 :
0xffffff8016c22f69  0xffffff808d19b1c0 : 0xffffff7f97a11fac 
0xffffff808d19b290 : 0xffffff7f97d7d53d  0xffffff808d19b350 :
0xffffff7f97e49d9e  0xffffff808d19b390 : 0xffffff7f97e49dfc 
0xffffff808d19b400 : 0xffffff7f980c35be  0xffffff808d19b530 :
0xffffff7f97e6dd41  0xffffff808d19b550 : 0xffffff7f97d8408d 
0xffffff808d19b600 : 0xffffff7f97d81bae  0xffffff808d19b800 :
0xffffff7f97d82af6  0xffffff808d19b8e0 : 0xffffff7f98288ba2 
0xffffff808d19b920 : 0xffffff7f9829855f  0xffffff808d19b940 :
0xffffff7f982c651b  0xffffff808d19b980 : 0xffffff7f982c657b 
0xffffff808d19b9c0 : 0xffffff7f9829dff5  0xffffff808d19ba10 :
0xffffff7f98269d3e  0xffffff808d19baa0 : 0xffffff7f98265cc7 
0xffffff808d19bad0 : 0xffffff7f98263816  0xffffff808d19bb00 :
0xffffff80170cb873  0xffffff808d19bb90 : 0xffffff80170cd76f 
0xffffff808d19bbf0 : 0xffffff80170cb28f  0xffffff808d19bd40 :
0xffffff8016cb6008  0xffffff808d19be50 : 0xffffff8016c26bb1 
0xffffff808d19be80 : 0xffffff8016c139b5  0xffffff808d19bef0 :
0xffffff8016c1e003  0xffffff808d19bf70 : 0xffffff8016cc921d 
0xffffff808d19bfb0 : 0xffffff8016cf3e26 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.12)[A4934A66-0E30-36E9-984A-650481102449]@0xffffff7f97a04000->0xffffff7f97a16fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.12)[661E3C87-5B97-3272-88FF-B9BA9B6E24ED]@0xffffff7f979ee000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f971f7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f971fe000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f9794d000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7f979ff000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f97d2c000->0xffffff7f97f9afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f971fe000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f979f1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f9794d000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.1.8)[3666E0FC-87C7-3329-BD8C-2F1ADED100A4]@0xffffff7f97f9b000->0xffffff7f98247fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f97d2c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f971fe000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.1.8)[7DAF283F-6FD3-3783-B3CC-D23964F1B9B8]@0xffffff7f98248000->0xffffff7f98312fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f971fe000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f979f1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f9794d000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f97d2c000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version: 13B42

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT
2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393 Kernel slide:    
0x0000000016a00000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8016c00000 System model
name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 56743263941613 last loaded kext at
378608602775: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr
0xffffff7f9746c000, size 65536) last unloaded kext at 463563131561:
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f9746c000, size
57344) loaded kexts: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs    2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60 com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124 com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X  7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1 com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0 com.apple.BootCache   35
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 153
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily   10.0.7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1 com.apple.vecLib.kext  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6 com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21 com.apple.driver.DiskImages  371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4 com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0 Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM
MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC
1.58f17 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256
MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE,
0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2
GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93),
Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22) Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6
12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network
Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: Hitachi
HTS545032B9SA02, 320.07 GB Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader USB Device:
Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub USB
Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device: Hub USB Device: IR
Receiver USB Device: Built-in iSight Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: run the disk test just for the heck of it.

Comment: disable graphics switching to test this -->Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - someone can explain the dump, but that someone is Apple's engineering staff. From a user perspective, you'd need about 10 to 20 dumps to start correlating times and patterns and comparing the dump reasons to know if you have some odd timing issue, a hardware issue or some other software cause to the panics.

I would review the other answers on kernel panics here and collect a `sysdiagnose` each time you restart after a panic. Save them off Mac so that you have a nice collection of dates/times and the saved logs to analyze should you enroll Apple or DIY analyze them.

- [What is a Kernel Panic and what does it mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean)